# Youtube iFrame, preview image not appearing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have this youtube embed video:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9NAG-3hwvS0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but in google chrome, the preview image does not appear. Why? It works in firefox and ie, but not chrome

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: height 700? Anyway, I'm in chrome on OSX, embedded perfectly for me

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of what I see.

Comment: and if you click it?

Comment: Same problem i am facing but nothing find out till now

Comment: @user979331 Though it's a very old question, I have a similar problem, with the difference that the whole player is not shown. I am wondering if you have any idea what the reason could be.